# Correct way to send a statement as a Func<Task>

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, async-await, func

I made a small benchmarking library that takes in `Func<Task>` objects, runs them a certain number of times and uses a `Stopwatch` object to figure out the average time it took to run:

```cs
public static async Task<BenchmarkResults> BenchmarkAsync(Func<Task> action, int repetitions, bool singleCore)
{
    // Run func, time it each time, compute average, return results.
}
```

I have made a small `IBenchmark` interface with a single `Run()` method. The way I am currently using this library is making benchmark classes that implement `IBenchmark` and passing a lambda that calls the `Run` method to it. Those `IBenchmark` objects are added to DI via an extension method:

```cs
var results = AsyncBenchmarker.BenchmarkAsync(async () => await benchmark.Run(), attribute.Repetitions, false).Result;
```

I would like to move away from needing this `IBenchmark` interface in the first place, it is getting in my way more than anything at this point. What I would like to do instead of passing `benchmark.Run()` in my lambda is pass a reflective invocation of another method in that same class. I tried something like this:

```cs
AsyncBenchmarker.BenchmarkAsync(async () => 
    await benchmark.GetType().GetMethod("SomeOtherMethod").Invoke(benchmark, null), attribute.Repetitions, false).Wait();
```

The problem is that `Invoke` returns a nullable object and I need this to be awaitable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Cast the result of your `Invoke` to `Task`?

Comment: I changed the code to this : results = AsyncBenchmarker.BenchmarkAsync(async () => 
                    await (Task) type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.DeclaringType != typeof(object) && m.Name != "Run").FirstOrDefault()
                        .Invoke(benchmark, null), attribute.Repetitions, false).Result;

I did not know you could typecast something to a Task, thanks!  There is however a small but measurable overhead from calling this reflectively (less than a millisecond).  Any way around this?

Comment: Yes; don't do that.

Comment: That's fair XD!  I'll keep digging but at least I have this in my back pocket if all else fails.  Cheers!